# Need to fill a next empty cell in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a new dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
###creating a dataframe:
bb=pd.DataFrame(columns = ['INDate', 'INCOME', 'EXDate','EXPENSE'])
bb.to_excel('/py/deleteafter/bb_black_book.xlsx')
bb.head()
```

I can see new dataframe without rows:

[image: headers]

Then I need to add a new value to the one of columns by cycle.

```py
income_value=message.text ###It is depend from the user input
for i in range(len(bb)):
    print(bb['INCOME'][i])
    if bb['INCOME'][i] != 'NaN':
        i += 1
       #print('NOT_EMPTY_CELL')
    else:
        #print('ive found an empty cell=)')
        bb['INCOME'][i]=income_value
        break
```

And here I met an errors, cause my df have a 0 length:

```py
print(range(len(bb)))
range(0, 0)
```

I don't sure that my solution is right, and I'm sure there is more simply solution might be. In overall, my main idea is:
How I can check a next empty cell in certain column (in my case column `'INCOME'`) to add the value to this FREE cell?
Or more simply - I need to add a value to the next not filled cell=)

Will be glad for your replies.

Comment: You can try doing `bb['income'] = income_value` for single value or `bb['income'] = pd.Series(income_value)` for list of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the last valid value you can use [last_valid_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html). It outputs a nan when the dataframe is empty, so you could do:

```
idx = bb["INCOME"].last_valid_index())
import numpy as np
if np.isnan(idx) or idx is None:
    bb.loc[0, "INCOME"] = income_value
else:
    bb.loc[idx + 1, "INCOME"] = income_value
```

Comment: But how I can fix a problem, when my dataframe is empty? If df is empty, or first row contains only NaN values - your method is not worked, cause `idx = None` for the values in first row =(

Comment: I added `or idx is None` to the solution so now works with None.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to append a row, e.g.:

```
row = {'INCOME': 20000, 'EXdate': '14/09/2020'} 
df= df.append(pd.DataFrame(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data in one column only where the index number doesn't exist, use loc

Change line

```
bb['INCOME'][i]=income_value
```

to

```
bb.loc[i,'INCOME']=income_value
```

and it should work fine.